# AWS CodeBuild DOWNLOAD_SOURCE failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, continuous-deployment, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am using AWS Code Pipeline to perform deployment, I manage to perform the deployment by using only CodeBuild, but when I changed it to S3 source, deployment always fails with error message:-
`Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE`

My CodeBuild project is created from the CodePipeline as pointed out by [others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48824667/4595687). I have also assigned it full access to my S3 out of desperation. But still to no avail.

My CodeBuild project service role policy is as below:-

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "s3:*",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline-ap-southeast-1-625xxxxxxx/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline-ap-southeast-1-625xxxxxxx/octen_frontend_prod/SourceArti/*",
                "arn:aws:logs:ap-southeast-1:57313xxxxxxx:log-group:/aws/codebuild/MyApp",
                "arn:aws:logs:ap-southeast-1:57313xxxxxxx:log-group:/aws/codebuild/MyApp:*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:*",
                "s3:ListJobs",
                "s3:CreateJob",
                "s3:HeadBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:ap-southeast-1:5731xxxxxxxx:log-group:/aws/codebuild/MyApp",
                "arn:aws:logs:ap-southeast-1:5731xxxxxxxx:log-group:/aws/codebuild/MyApp:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok.. so CodeBuild only accepts `zip` format, whereas I was providing it a `tar` artifact.
In fact, the **Phase Details** section under CodeBuild's detail page actually provided the error reason which was 
`CLIENT_ERROR: zip: not a valid zip file for primary source`. How did I miss that makes me wonder...

Comment: I am also facing the same error. How did you run the build with the .tar.gz?